# Take app version from apk or ipa

Tags: gluon, gluon-mobile, javafxports

I would like to take app version from ipa file or apk file; I use gluon mobile and so I want to read value from native app,  How can I do that?

Comment: Can you elaborate your question? Do you have the Gluon Mobile app source code? Then the version is specified in both AndroidManifest.xml and Default-info.plist files. If you have the binaries only, I'm not sure if platform apps (Android Studio, Xcode) will read the apk/ipa files. Can't you install them directly on devices and look for app info?

Comment: up vote
0
down vote
accept
Ok, I try to give you more info: In my app (made with gluon mobile) I want to take the version of app to log request to my BackEnd; in Android apk the version app is into manifest, I found this code to take the app version

PackageInfo pInfo = this.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(getPackageName(), 0); String version = pInfo.versionName;

I hope that thre is a plugin into charm down; isn't so?

Comment: There is no plugin for what you are asking yet. The closest one is the [DeviceService](https://bitbucket.org/gluon-oss/charm-down/src/153d43c06ff1/plugins/plugin-device/?at=default). Maybe you can file an issue on it? It should be possible to extend the service with your request.